# Blackberry Mobile Web App Shortcut

Tags: java, blackberry, mobile, java-me

I want to provide an option to download blackberry shortcut of my mobile site. As far as I understand I need a link like this:

```
<a href="desc.jad" type="text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor">download shortcut</a>
```

And jad file contains description of a jar file, icon image etc. in plain text. I've never used Blackberry SDK before, so I'd really appreciate it if someone can explain the steps to provide this kind of functionality to users. Do I need to create an application from scratch or is there a a straightforward way to create mobile web app shortcuts?

You can see an example at espn.com mobile site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have both a `.jad` (descriptor) and a `.cod` (binary) file
Put them on you web server in the same folder. Then create the link to point to the `.jad` file as you have now.

You probably need to set the mime types (this varies depending your web server) 
OR you can set it in a `.htaccess` file like this:

```
AddType text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor .jad
AddType application/vnd.rim.cod .cod
```

Also, have you read this guide?
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/Testing_and_Deployment_of_Applications@tkb/117/1/How_to_Deploy_and_Distribute_Applications_V1.pdf

You want to do deploy "Over the Air", on page 17.

It pretty much explains everything I just wrote above.

Comment: Looks like the native app launches the mobile web site, presumably in the blackberry browser.